# beautifulsoup findAll resulting null with div tag

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap the comments from the following link: 
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/175927790/tupi-2d-animation-software-for-everyone/comments

Using code :

```
urlcomments = url +str("/comments")
htmlcomments=urllib2.urlopen(urlcomments).read()                
commentsoup=BeautifulSoup(htmlcomments, "html.parser")
commentable = soup.findAll('section',attrs={"class_":"js-could-have-comments js-project-comments-content js-project-content project-content"})
```

I have tried urllib and urllib2 both but none of them is working , the result of the findAll is [].
Also i have tried different tags within the html , div  with class is not working with as well.

This piece of code is a part of a class , so if anybody needs some more info on it please let me know.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if you want to use key word args in findall, you need to use `class_` , but when you use `attr={}`, there is no need to use extra '_' in the class's tail.'class' is a key in the dictionary. so just change you code to this:

```
commentable = soup.findAll('section',attrs={"class":"js-could-have-comments js-project-comments-content js-project-content project-content"})
```

besides that, this page is rendered by javascript, so, you can not get the javascript part by urllib or requests, i recommend use selenium.

> It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but
>   the name of the CSS attribute, “class”, is a reserved word in Python.
>   Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of
>   Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword
>   argument class_:

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "sister"})
```

[BeautifulSoup Doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes)

Comment: Tried that , Still not working , The most confusing part is that the code above this part is working fine , its like somehow it does not access this section of html. I dont know to diagnose it further.